# Optimal path proposed by pgr_astar is not the optimal one?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, astar

I'm using the function pgr_astar function of PostgreSQL to find the optimal path between two points in the dataset of Chicago.

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT a.seq, a.id1 AS node, a.id2 AS edge, b.source, b.target, b.cost, b.reverse_cost, b.km, b.estimated_time as time, b.ang_elev, b.geom_way 
 FROM pgr_astar 
('SELECT id, source, target, cost as cost, x1, y1, x2, y2, reverse_cost FROM chicago_2po_4pgr', 48,89654, true, true)as a LEFT JOIN chicago_2po_4pgr as b  
ON a.id2 = b.id 
order by seq
```

I want to find the most fuel efficient path, the columns cost and reverse cost present the fuel consumed by each segment.
The path proposed by the function is the green one.
BUT, I found a path that have a total fuel consumption less than the proposed one (the yellow path)

Any explanation please? Why didn't the function propose me the yellow path?

[image]

Comment: Two options. 1st highly likely that your manual calcs aren't correct, because yellow looks much longer. 2nd is missing node in your network.

Comment: Have you tried with Dijkstra?

Comment: @FelixIP thank you for commenting the yellow path is really much longer but is optimal on fuel consumption (have less total fuel consumed than the green one), the column cost that I mentionned on the query as cost have the fuel consumed of each road segement, so I'm expexcting to have the optimal path regarding to the fuel consumption.

Comment: @dkastl thank you for commenting but I'm working on a project in which I should use A star algorithm.

Comment: It is also possible that there is a gap in the network were one edge does not actually connect with another. Try looking at the `source` and `target` attributes of your yellow path and see if you actually can travel along that string of node ids.

Comment: Yes I know it is about fuel, because I read your post. I am having trouble to imagine that almost twice longer route is more efficient, unless there are mountain pass with 30 degrees climbes along green one or multiple faulty traffic lights.

Comment: My suggestion is to use Dijkstra once to make sure the results are not different. It's as quick to do as writing an answer here ;-) If Dijkstra does not return the expected result either, then it's likely your network topology or cost settings. With A* there is a chance that the heuristic component causes the result you see. If you expect A* to be faster, that's not the case ... at least you almost can't measure the difference.

Comment: @FelixoP, whatever you visually see on the map, that appears to be longer, does not matter, if the cost component for "length" is very little. If the fuel consumption is the relevant cost for pgRouting, then it will minimize by that cost, not the length.

Comment: @Reem, you should better render a map, that displays the cost of each road segment.

Comment: @dkastl I ruuned Dijkstra and it returns the same result as a star function :/ I verified the connection of these two paths and nothing goes wrong, segemnts are correctly connected. I still have not found the reason why it proposes the green one not the yellow. FelixIP, 1saac, dkastl Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: @Reem, if you can provide a small dataset, that is enough to reproduce the problem, you could send it to the pgRouting users mailing list.